# Docker inside LXD starting container process caused "apply caps: operation not permitted"

Tags: docker, lxd

I got this error when trying to run a docker container inside an LXD container

gpu is required to run this docker container(I think this might have an effect

```
(base) root@sim2real:~# sudo docker start sim2real_server
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: apply caps: operation not permitted: unknown
Error: failed to start containers: sim2real_server
(base) root@sim2real:~#
```

I have configured the lxd container as the following after looking at other answers

```
lxc config show sim2real
architecture: x86_64
config:
  image.architecture: amd64
  image.description: Ubuntu focal amd64 (20220305_07:42)
  image.os: Ubuntu
  image.release: focal
  image.serial: "20220305_07:42"
  image.type: squashfs
  image.variant: default
  raw.lxc: lxc.cgroup.devices.allow=a lxc.apparmor.profile=unconfined lxc.cap.drop=
    lxc.mount.auto=cgoup:rw:force
  security.nesting: "true"
  security.privileged: "true"
  security.syscalls.intercept.mknod: "true"
  security.syscalls.intercept.setxattr: "true"
  volatile.base_image: 6f1c83cc14bfd1442678132bb67bb62d2eace4473fbf16d4b40c5e3aa8c8993f
  volatile.eth0.host_name: vethf369ca4a
  volatile.eth0.hwaddr: 00:16:3e:a2:1d:23
  volatile.idmap.base: "0"
  volatile.idmap.current: '[]'
  volatile.idmap.next: '[]'
  volatile.last_state.idmap: '[]'
  volatile.last_state.power: RUNNING
  volatile.uuid: 20a1b524-f313-43c9-b0e3-f8f41c18b52a
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: lxdbr0
    type: nic
  gpu:
    type: gpu
  proxy0:
    bind: host
    connect: tcp:10.241.91.250:22
    listen: tcp:10.178.2.168:6003
    type: proxy
  proxy1:
    bind: host
    connect: tcp:10.241.91.250:4000
    listen: tcp:10.178.2.168:6004
    type: proxy
  sharefile:
    path: /home/share
    source: /home/wzy/Downloads
    type: disk
ephemeral: false
profiles:
- default
stateful: false
description: ""
```

But the problem still exists, how should I solve it

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same error message when trying to start some containers using docker-compose INSIDE LXC container.

I found that those containers has configuration

```
privileged: true
```

on my docker-compose.yml, which is already given by lxc config.
Removing this line from .yml solved the problem. Hope this helps.

Notes about my environment:

- docker: 20.10.14-ce
- docker-compose: 1.16.1
- LXD/LXC: 5.2 (installed via snap)

refs:

- https://github.com/home-assistant/core/issues/64578